# Jira API - Add attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jira, jira-rest-api

A Ruby gem for the JIRA REST API https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby

How to add one or more attachments to an issue.

EDIT #1

[**JIRA REST API:** Issue attachments](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/?_ga=1.53606696.1839169166.1467707774#api/2/issue/%7BissueIdOrKey%7D/attachments-addAttachment)

Any suggestions about it?

EDIT #2

I figured out how to save some attachment but with curl only.

```
curl -D- -u "username:password" -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file=@tmp/1.jpg" "https://jira.you_end_point/rest/api/2/issue/"issue-ID"/attachments"
```

Comment: What does `using this gem for exist issue` mean?

Comment: EDIT #1.   - Create issue in Jira; - Add file to an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This is my solution***

**rest-client gem**

```
require 'rest-client'
resource = RestClient::Resource.new(url, username, password)
response = resource.post({ file: File.new(path)}, { "X-Atlassian-Token" => "nocheck"} )
response.code.eql?(200) # ok status ;)
```

After this you probably need to delete local file..

I hope this will help!)
done